# Dojo datagrid disable focus

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid, dojox.grid

I am trying to create a matrix using dojox.Datagrid I have disabled the rows and cells in javascript with pointerEvents:none. My probelm is that in IE 11 the double click on the cell messes with the layout scrollbars. I looked into it and it is the cell focus event that does this. Is there any way to disable focus for a DataGrid? I have not found an answer in the API. My datagrid is already created with editable false.

Answer (score 0):

Whether a widget is focusable or not depends on the tabIndex attribute of the corresponding DOM node. Maybe removing it from your Datagrid will do the job.

[Have a look here.](http://snook.ca/archives/accessibility_and_usability/elements_focusable_with_tabindex)